# Unexpected regex pattern matching

Tags: regex, rust, regex-group

I'd like to match only for python-like floats, that is for example: `0.1`, `.1` or `0.`. I wrote this regex: `r"(\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+)"` and found out that it also matches with `"(.6"`, which I haven't intended. My guess is it has something to do with grouping with parenthesis, but I haven't escaped any parenthesis with a backslash.

I'm using version 1.7.1 of [regex crate](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html) and cargo 1.67.0.

```rust
use regex::Regex;
fn main() {
    let pattern = Regex::new(r"^(\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+)").unwrap();
    assert!(pattern.is_match("(.6"));
}
```

Comment: `is_match()` returns true if the pattern can be matched anywhere in the string. If you want to test the entire string, add `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add ^ in the question but either way program doesn't panic.

Comment: Note that your regex also matches `౪.౮` because `\d` is Unicode aware. You probably want `(?-u:\d)` or, equivalently, `[0-9]`. Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4fbb8fe86c25363ddcf971feb0f1e38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `^(\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+)` matches `^(\d+\.?\d*)` or `(\.\d+)`.

You want to have `^(\d+\.?\d*)|^(\.\d+)` or add another group. `^((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+))`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the precedence of `|` and `^` operators